# How do I filter a stream of integers into a list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to process a stream of `Integers` and collect the integers that match a predicate (via the `compare()` function) into a list. Here's a rough outline of the code I've written.

```
private List<Integer> process() {
    Z z = f(-1);
    return IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .filter(i -> compare(z, f(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)); // Error on this line
}

private boolean compare(Z z1, Z z2) { ... }
private Z f(int i) { ... }
```

Unfortunately my solution does not compile and I cannot make sense of the compiler error for the line highlighted:

> The method collect(Supplier<R>, ObjIntConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Object,capture#1-of ?,Collection<Object>>)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IntStream` doesn't contain a `collect` method that accepts a single argument of type `Collector`. `Stream` does. Therefore you have to convert your `IntStream` to a `Stream` of objects.

You can either box the `IntStream` into a `Stream<Integer>` or use `mapToObj` to achieve the same.

For example:

```
return IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .filter(i -> compare(z, f(i)))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

`boxed()` will return a Stream consisting of the elements of this stream, each boxed to an Integer.

or

```
return IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .filter(i -> compare(z, f(i)))
    .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Perfect - your suggestion fixed my problem. It also got me wondering if perhaps I should have set up a stream of `Integers` instead and avoid the need to box. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: @dave Don't. Starting with `int` values mean that only values that pass the filter will be boxed. If you box to `Integer` before the filter, you're wasting resources.

Comment: @dave That depends on the source of your data. If you start with primitives, it makes sense to use an `IntStream` (until you have to put the `int` elements into a `List`, which only takes `Integer`s).

Comment: @dave BTW, if you don't absolutely require to collect the elements into a List, you can consider collecting them into an `int[]` by calling `toArray` instead of `collect`.

Answer (score 3):

*Or* you can specify the `Supplier, Accumulator and Combiner` yourself:

```
 IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .filter(i -> compare(z, f(i)))  
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```